# Java matrix initialisation

Tags: java, matrix

I've been programming in Java for 3 years now, I know how to initialise a matrix but I've been courious about the difference between this

```
double[][] matrix = new double[rows][];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new double[columns];
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = 0.0d;
    }
}
```

and this

```
double[][] matrix = new double[rows][columns];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = 0.0d;
    }
}
```

They seem to be initialised the same way, but I've been told the first way is better, but I don't know why. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: With the first variant you _could_ have different row lengths - for most matrices that probably wouldn't make sense though. Thus I'd go for the second variant because that's the better readable one (and maybe replace the inner loop with `Arrays.fill( matrix[i], 0.0);`).

Comment: By the way, `new double[rows][columns]` will set the all the values to zeros, so there's no need to do that in a loop.

Comment: @AlexShesterov you're right, how could I miss that? ;) - that would make version 2 a one-liner which is _very_ easy to read.

Comment: @AlexShesterov yes, I know that, I just wrote that there to clarify I am asserting a value to the indexes, Anyway thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think one approach can be categorized as strictly better then other. You will use either of two depending on your use-case.

For example, the benefit of first approach: you can have `matrix` with different sizes of columns. Also, the `matrix` initialization is deferred (memory is not allocated). E.g.:

```
double[][] matrix = new double[2][]; // memory is not allocated yet
matrix[0] = new double[] {1.0};
matrix[1] = new double[] {1.0, 2.0};
```

On the other hand, second approach allows to create and initialize `matrix` in one step, when you know the `matrix` has fixed dimensions (`rows` & `columns`):

```
double[][] matrix = new double[2][2]; // memory is allocated for double 2x2 matrix
```

Comment: Yeah I've been working only with matrices lately (by which I mean each row had same amount of columns) so I totally forgot this is an option :P

Answer (score 0):

When you print the two arrays just after their declaration statements, one reason becomes obvious:

The first one prints `[null, null]`, and the second one `[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]` (tested with `rows = 2` and `columns = 3`)

The first one only initializes inner arrays when their data is available, whereas the second one creates and initializes those inner arrays with zeros (the default value for `double`). This difference is essentially about when objects are created (and the consequence of that on memory use). For small arrays, this difference is likely to be negligible.

Beside this, inner arrays aren't required to be of the same length, so:

- `double[][] matrix = new double[rows][columns]` forces all inner arrays to be of length `columns`.
- `double[][] matrix = new double[rows][]` allows you to add `new double[12]` to the outer array, thus inner arrays can have different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Actually both ways are overly bloated,
because the initializing of the `double[]` sub-arrays with `0.0`
is already done implicitly.
Therefore you don't need to do it explicitly.

You can therefore write it like this and still have the same effect:

```
double[][] matrix = new double[rows][];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new double[columns];
}
```

or

```
double[][] matrix = new double[rows][columns];
```

I would prefer the last one, because it is the most simple.